# cannot receive any push notification on react native android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I am following this documentation for receiving push notification on react native android https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm, I am able to receive the device token id, but I am not able to receive any notification when I am using sending manually from firebase using that device id:

This is the code on my react native app:

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import FCM, {FCMEvent, RemoteNotificationResult, WillPresentNotificationResult, NotificationType} from 'react-native-fcm';

// this shall be called regardless of app state: running, background or not running. Won't be called when app is killed by user in iOS
FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
    // there are two parts of notif. notif.notification contains the notification payload, notif.data contains data payload
    if(notif.local_notification){
      //this is a local notification
    }
    if(notif.opened_from_tray){
      //iOS: app is open/resumed because user clicked banner
      //Android: app is open/resumed because user clicked banner or tapped app icon
    }
    // await someAsyncCall();

    if(Platform.OS ==='ios'){
      //optional
      //iOS requires developers to call completionHandler to end notification process. If you do not call it your background remote notifications could be throttled, to read more about it see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application.
      //This library handles it for you automatically with default behavior (for remote notification, finish with NoData; for WillPresent, finish depend on "show_in_foreground"). However if you want to return different result, follow the following code to override
      //notif._notificationType is available for iOS platfrom
      switch(notif._notificationType){
        case NotificationType.Remote:
          notif.finish(RemoteNotificationResult.NewData) //other types available: RemoteNotificationResult.NewData, RemoteNotificationResult.ResultFailed
          break;
        case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
          notif.finish();
          break;
        case NotificationType.WillPresent:
          notif.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All) //other types available: WillPresentNotificationResult.None
          break;
      }
    }
});
FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, (token) => {
    console.log(token)
    // fcm token may not be available on first load, catch it here
});

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // iOS: show permission prompt for the first call. later just check permission in user settings
        // Android: check permission in user settings
        FCM.requestPermissions().then(()=>console.log('granted')).catch(()=>console.log('notification permission rejected'));

        FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
            console.log(token)
            // store fcm token in your server
        });

        this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
            // optional, do some component related stuff
        });

        // initial notification contains the notification that launchs the app. If user launchs app by clicking banner, the banner notification info will be here rather than through FCM.on event
        // sometimes Android kills activity when app goes to background, and when resume it broadcasts notification before JS is run. You can use FCM.getInitialNotification() to capture those missed events.
        // initial notification will be triggered all the time even when open app by icon so send some action identifier when you send notification
        FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif => {
           console.log(notif)
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // stop listening for events
        this.notificationListener.remove();
    }
```

Android Manifest file looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="fi.rogerstudio.possis"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.healthgps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Light"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
              android:launchMode="singleTop">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="exp6a747c4f7f604b89a93d9f3d281cbb77"/>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.MessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
      </service>

    <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- The Facebook SDK runs FacebookInitProvider on startup and crashes if there isn't an ID here -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb0"/>
    <!-- react-native-background-geolocation licence -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.license" android:value="14ef777231a8412c8b2d109443999356a2c13e62c07e2868345f5e13f01b3c83" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRLocalMessagingPublisher"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRSystemBootEventReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                  <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: When you close your app and quite the background running, does your app could received the Notification or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see your current problem is about your installed package. You made some conflict package install.

Please remove **io.invertase.firebase.messaging** from your app.

> npm uninstall react-native-firebase --save

Then you also need to remove from your **settings.gradle**